# Wireshark not capturing HTTP response/request from/to loopback IP

Tags: c, linux, http, server, wireshark

I'm programming a simple web server in C. This is an example of the HTTP response the server generates:

> "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\nContent-Length: " + length + "\r\n\r\n" + resource

I used the loopback IP to access my web server (127.0.0.1) on port 9999. Upon typing 127.0.0.1:9999 on the web browser (firefox, the web page is loaded just fine. However, Wireshark is not showing neither of the HTTP request by the browser nor the HTTP response by the server, it actually doesn't capture any packets from/to 127.0.0.1.

Below is an example of an HTTP request received by the server:

```
    GET / HTTP/1.1
    Host: 127.0.0.1:9999
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Connection: keep-alive
    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

And the HTTP response generated by the server:

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Content-Type: text/html
    Content-Length: 97

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <h2>HTML Page Test</h2>
    <p>Very simple page</p>


    </body>
    </html>
```

What could be the root of the problem?

Comment: This is not really a C question nor a programming question. It seems more like a question on how to use wireshark and would be more suitable for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: You need to have pcap capture on the loopback device (called "lo" normally, not e.g. any ethernet devices such as eth0 )